# which error is it - a semantic error or a link error?

Tags: compilers

I am having a simple doubt in C programming language.

**In any simple C code snippet, if by mistake suppose i have written intmain()** **instead of main().**

Then it represents what type of error ?

---

It will not be a lexical error as compiler will correctly make a token for it and it is also not a syntax error clearly.

I think it is a semantic error as in this phase compiler checks with the meaningful statements, scoping, binding, variable not declared, function not declared, any variable declared twice, etc.

---

But, on the other hand, I also think it as a linker error as in the semantic phase, it can throw a error that function intmain() is not declared and it is been directly used.

---

**Can anyone make this crystal clear that what is the actual error ?**

Comment: I would guess that it would be a linker error only if there was an extern declaration of that symbol beforehand. Otherwise, it would be a semantic error.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis, I didn't get what u said !! Can you plz elaborate or answer, if possible .

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis, Why did you remove your answer ?

Comment: I realized it wasn't as relevant to the question as I thought when I wrote it.

Answer (score 1):

We can reproduce your error using this C++ code:

```
intmain() {
    return 0;
}
```

The following error is returned during compile time:

```
error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘intmain’ with no type [-fpermissive]
```

Every function in C/C++ has to have a type. In this sense, it's a type error, which falls in the category of (static) semantic errors. On the other hand, your error is caused by a typo. This sort of error is considered a lexical error, which falls under syntax errors.

There is a lot of [discussion](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-relationship-between-syntax-static-semantics-and-semantics) whether certain errors are syntactical or static semantic. My opinion is this case is that the error is lexical, considering the cause.

Comment: In C89, function declarations with no type specifiers is allowed however, which implicitly gives the function a return type of `int`. (See section 3.5.2)

This means that depending on which version of the language you're talking about (GCC defaults to C89 even today), this is either a syntax error or a semantic error. In C89, the function `intmain() {...}` compiles just fine on every version of GCC; it just doesn't have a `main` symbol.